# How to change lost email massage on WordPress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I would like to change my "lost password" email text for my multisite. I have tried some of the solution. But, none of these worked for me. No matter what I did, I always get the default email.
Any kind of help would me appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "I have tried some of the solution" - Please update your question to include what you've tried (with code, not pictures) and you'll likely get some help.

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use filters for a custom password reset mail:

- [retrieve_password_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_title/) for the email's subject and
- [retrieve_password_message](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_message/) for the email's body

Here's a working example:

```
function reset_pass_subject($subject) {
    $title = __( 'Password Reset Request' );
    return $title;
}
add_filter('retrieve_password_title', 'reset_pass_subject');

function reset_pass_email($message, $reset_key, $user_login, $user_data) {
    $link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=' . $reset_key . '&login=' . rawurlencode($user_login);
    ob_start();
    ?>
        <h1>YOUR TITLE</h1>
        <p>Enter what you want here</p>
        <p>Do not forget the <?= $link;?></p>
        <p>Thanks!</p>
    <?php
    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $message;
}
add_filter('retrieve_password_message', 'reset_pass_email', 10, 4);
```

Code goes in your `functions.php` or a custom plugin.
Tested and works in single WordPress and multisite.